# How do I code a close link to js accordion panels?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a lot of content and the panels gets really long. I want the option to close each panel individually with a close link at the bottom inside that panel. I'm using the animated accordion code from :

http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp

How do I alter the script/css for the close link to work? I don't want to use jQuery for this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
}

div.panel.show {
    opacity: 1;
    max-height: 500px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Animated Accordion</h2>

<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p><a href="#" class="close">Close</a></p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p><a href="#" class="close">Close</a></p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div id="foo" class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p><a href="#" class="close">Close</a></p>
</div>

<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function(){
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please add a link to a demo or create a fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get all the elements with class `close` then attach click to every one, the click should go up to the parent panel and remove the class `active`, I think you're looking for :

```
var closes = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

for (var j = 0; j < closes.length; j++) {
    closes[j].onclick = function(){
        this.parentElement.parentElement.classList.remove("show");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function(){
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
  }
}

var closes = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

for (var j = 0; j < closes.length; j++) {
  closes[j].onclick = function(){
    this.parentElement.parentElement.classList.remove("show");
    
    var section_title = this.parentElement.parentElement.previousSibling;
    section_title.previousElementSibling.classList.remove("active");
  }
}
```

```css
button.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

div.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}

div.panel.show {
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Animated Accordion</h2>

<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p><a href="#" class="close">Close</a></p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p><a href="#" class="close">Close</a></p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div id="foo" class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p><a href="#" class="close">Close</a></p>
</div>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
```

Comment: Hi Zakaria - I just noticed this, after clicking close, the button/header stays in the active state bg color (the darker gray). Is there any way to have it return to the inital state (lighter gray)? If not, no biggie. Tia

Comment: Zakaria - where do you recommend to learn javascript? Tia again!

Comment: Zakaria - is there javascript to keep an opened panel open after a page refresh?

Comment: You could use the `localStorage` of `cookies` to store the status of panel in the client side, then after refresh get the status and open/close panel depending to this status.

Comment: I have no idea how to do that - are there examples online I could model this on?